# Passing an Lvalue to a parameter of RValue

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue-reference

I wanted to know how this is possible ?

```
template<typename T>
void Test(T&& arg)
{
    arg = 14;
}


int a = 23;
Test(a);
```

My question is that the function Test requires an argument of type Rvalue however it seems to also accept parameter of type lvalue. Why is that ? Is that because of presence of templates ? Because If i do something like this

```
void AnotherTest(int&& arg)
{
    arg = 14;
}
```

Then the function requires the parameter to be of type Rvalue.
I would appreciate it if someone could explain why presence of Templates changes the behavior.

Comment: Look up "reference collapsing" and "universal references".

Comment: `T&&` is not an rvalue-reference (while `int&&` is). It will be *deduced* to either an rvalue- or lvalue-reference, depending on the value category of the argument expression. Scott Meyers [calls it](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) a *universal reference*.

Comment: @jrok: Approximately, but not truly correct. The template arguments are *deduced*, not the template function parameters. The type for the argument will then be an *rvalue-reference* to the deduced type, which might end up being an *lvalue-reference* argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key, as you correctly imagined, is that it is a template *and* that the argument type is being *deduced*. When you call `Test` with an lvalue, the rules for argument type deduction *when the argument is an rvalue-reference* will deduce the type `T` to be an *lvalue-reference*, and thus the specialization becomes:

```
template <>
void Test<int&>(int & && arg)
```

At this point the reference collapsing rules kick in and the type of the argument becomes:

```
template <>
void Test<int&>(int & arg)
```

While the template takes an *rvalue-reference*, if the type is an *lvalue-reference* the argument becomes an *lvalue-reference* itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that because of presence of templates ?

Somewhat, but not strictly speaking. More precisely, this behavior occurs because you have an alias for a reference type. A template parameter is the most likely scenario where you would see this, but you can synthesize the behavior without templates.

```cpp
using T = int&; // Alias, not a template parameter

void AnotherTest(T&& arg)
{
    arg = 14;
}
```

Instead of using a template parameter as an alias, I've employed the `using` keyword (a `typedef` would also work). Just like in your template setup, an rvalue reference to an lvalue reference [collapses](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing) to an lvalue reference. That is, `T&&` is the same as `T` in this case. So you can invoke `AnotherTest(a)` and have `arg` bind to `a`.

---

On the flip side, you can keep your template and still replicate the error. The key is to specify the template argument instead of letting it be deduced.

```cpp
    Test<int>(a);
```

> `error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'int&&' to lvalue of type 'int'`

The gist of the above is that you probably misunderstood what the compiler deduced your template parameter as. When you invoked `Test(a)`, you probably thought `T` was `int`, but your compiler – which has the final say in the matter – decided that `T` was `int&`.