# lvalue and rvalue as function parameters

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, template-argument-deduction, const-reference, reference-binding

I'm trying to understand Lvalue and Rvalue in C ++.

So I'm using them as parameters passed to the functions.
In this first case I have two functions, the first has a reference to an const int, in this case thanks to "const" (see [link](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/understanding-meaning-lvalues-and-rvalues-c)) I can pass to the first function both a Lvalue and a Rvalue and I will have no problems.
At the second function instead I am obliged to pass a Rvlaue otherwise I get the error described.

```
void f1(const int& n){cout<<"[Lvalue]"<<endl;}
void f2(int&& n){cout<<"[Rvalue]"<<endl;}

int main()
{   
    const int n = 10;
    f1(n);
    f2(n);  //error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘int&&’ to lvalue of type ‘const int’

}
```

ok!

Why if the second function becomes a function template, as in the example below I can also pass a Lvalue.

```
void f1(const int& n){cout<<"[Lvalue]"<<endl;}
template<class T>
void f2(T&& n){cout<<"[Rvalue]"<<endl;}

int main()
{   
    const int n = 10;
    f1(n);
    f2(n); //ok
}
```

Comment: *rvalue reference* versus *forwarding reference* (`f2(T&&)`).

Comment: What Jarod means is that in the context of template argument deduction `T&&` can bind to lots of things that aren't necessarily r-value references!

Comment: "_I'm trying to understand Lvalue and Rvalue_" I don't see any rvalue here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing an Lvalue to a parameter of RValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598692/passing-an-lvalue-to-a-parameter-of-rvalue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is important is that `T` was deduced to be a reference. So, if `T` is `const int&`, then what is `T&&` i.e. `const int& &&`? *Reference collapsing* rules say that it is `const int&`.

So, when `T` in `T&&` is deduced, that `&&` doesn't denote rvalue reference, but a reference whose type is deduced, and may be either rvalue or lvalue reference depending on the result of the deduction. It is said to be a forwarding reference.