# why different unique_ptrs can point to "the same" object

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

First, consider the following code snippet.

```cpp
    double a = 10/3.0;
    std::unique_ptr<double> p1 = std::make_unique<double>(a);
    std::unique_ptr<double> p2 = std::make_unique<double>(a);
    assert(*p1 == *p2);
    printf("%p %p %p\n", &a, p1.get(), p2.get());
```

The output of the addresses of a , p1 and p2 is non-identical.

Then I changed the type `double` to `std::string` and `std::vector<int>`, the results remain similar.

My guess is that `p1` and `p1` make a copy of the original object `a`. These two pointers manage this copied object.

I am confused why made such a design looks violate the unique feature of unique_ptr.

Comment: *"why different unique_ptrs can point to the same object"* -- the fact that `p1.get()` and `p2.get()` (and `&a`) are different addresses indicates that they do NOT point to the same object.

Comment: They point to different objects having the same double value, you were sure only of it.

Comment: This is like saying two cars are the same car because they have the same make and model.

Comment: Here's a more direct test to see if the objects are the same. Right before your `assert`, add the line `*p1 = 10.0;`. (That is, change the value of `*p1` but do not directly change `*p2`. If the pointers point to the same object, then changing that object via one pointer one would change the object obtained via the other.) Are the pointed-to values still the same?

Comment: both `std::make_unique<double>(a)` expression create a separate new dynamically allocated `double` using `new double(a)` therefore not violating the uniqueness of ownership of the allocated memory. `new double(a)` indeed creates a copy, but uniqueness of the value is nothing the contract of `std::unique_ptr` promises.

Answer (score 3):

> why different unique_ptrs can point to the same object

`p1` and `p2` do not point to the same object. From [std::make_unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique):

> ```
> template< class T, class... Args > unique_ptr<T> make_unique( Args&&... args );   (1)
> ```
>
> **1)** Constructs a non-array type T. The arguments args are passed to the constructor of T. This overload participates in overload resolution only if T is not an array type. **The function is equivalent to**:
>
> `unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...))`

(end quote)

This means that the `a` that you're passing is used as an **initializer** to create a new separate dynamically allocated `double` with the same value as `a` has.

---

> The output of the addresses of a , p1 and p2 is non-identical.

This shows exactly that `p1` and `p2` point to different objects.

Comment: I have two questions, as `a` is lvalue, how can it pass to the `make_unique`  which takes a rvalue reference(&&).  Besides, what's the usage of the design that can make a `unique_ptr` points to a new separate dynamically allocated double. @Anoop Rana

Comment: @amont The answer to your first follow up question is that because the standard allows it. A more simplified example can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/HnCX3klOK). For explanation, refer to [Passing an Lvalue to a parameter of RValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598692/passing-an-lvalue-to-a-parameter-of-rvalue)

Comment: The answer to your second question is: In the cases, where you use dynamically allocated doubles, there is the notion of ownership. The owner makes sure, the object is valid as long as other code is using it and the owner destructs the object and deallocates the memory, when it is no longer needed. `unique_ptr` do that automatically, when the variable goes out of scope (e.g. at the end of the block for local variables or when the containing (and owning) object gets destructed for member variables. This works even for exceptions. The name `unique_ptr` comes from the unique *owner*.

Comment: It is supported that ownership is moved! But not copied! Then would be two owners and the object (double in this case) would be used after first deletion and deleted a second time.

Comment: @Sebastian Really really thank you. However, I still have no idea in which situation there is a need to make a new unique_ptr points to `the copy of `  an object which already exists.

Comment: @Sebastian And I don't understand what you said "It is supported that ownership is moved! But not copied! ".  I know unique_ptr can move ownership by `std::move`, and the original owner would be set as `nullptr`.

Comment: Yes, you understood moving ownership. In addition it is possible to get() a non-owning plain pointer from an owning one. However, it is (on purpose) not supported to copy ownership. If you tried to copy a `unique_ptr`, you would get a compilation error. Regardless whether the copy is into another `unique_ptr` variable or into a `unique_ptr` parameter of a called function.